# Passing scroll gesture to UIScrollView from another view

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, gesture, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I do have a view that has a UIScrollView and over it there is a view that display some text.
When the user swipes over this view that contains text the UIScrollView won't scroll. How to make this view transparent in a way it relays the swipe gesture to UIScrollView.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can just set

```
myTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Or, if you're creating your view with Interface Builder, there's a check box there called 'User interaction enabled', just uncheck that.

Comment: This will disable the buttons inside that text view. It has a play/stop button for the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [UIView hitTest Method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest%3awithEvent%3a)

> Returns the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy (including itself) that contains a specified point.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside the -touchesXXXX:withEvent: methods of your custom view, call their super methods to forward touch events.

For example:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  // forward touchesBegan to super class
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

  ... 
  // process touchesBegan for this view
}
```

Do the same things for touchesMoved, touchesEnded, and touchesCancelled.