# iOS : Transfer Scroll Gesture on a View to Another

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uigesturerecognizer

I have a screen with two views :

- An UITableView (tableView) on the right hand side, that takes half of the screen
- An UIView (controllerView) on the left hand side that takes the other half of the screen

Here's an example

[image: Tranfer Scroll to TableView]

I'd like the left view to "control" the UITableView : when the user scrolls from top to bottom, it should scroll the UITableView from top to bottom, as if the user would have made the same gesture but with a right offset.

I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720907/passing-scroll-gesture-to-uiscrollview-from-another-view), but no answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add touches handling methods to your Control View (controllerView)

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html

Calculate change of Y coordinate of touch and scroll tableView with

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

method.

Comment: Interesting, I've tried this, I used the tableView's contentOffset instead. It works fine, but I'd like to have the deceleration effect.  Wouldn't this be possible with UIGestureRecognizer ?

Comment: Well Actually it is possible. With UIPanGestureRecognizer you get the deceleration for free, but setting the contentOffset with animation is not such a good idea, because if the user tries to scroll while the tableView is animating, it will look jerky. I don't know how apple does, probably not with the standard animation API. I accepted the answer, because it made me find the solution, I'll post something more complete when I'll have time.